# WP - REST API выдал неожиданный результат

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, site

Делаю сайт на WP. У меня появилась ошибка: `Ошибка обновления. Ответ не является допустимым ответом JSON.`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заглянул в здоровье сайта и увидел:

```
REST API выдал неожиданный результат
-----
REST API — один из способов коммуникации WordPress и других приложений с сервером. К примеру, экран редактора блоков использует его для отображения и сохранения ваших записей и страниц.

Запрос к REST API завершился с неожиданным результатом: (404) <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p> <hr> <address>Apache/2.4.38 (Raspbian) Server at 192.168.1.8 Port 80</address> </body></html> .
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Посмотри на IP в ошибке. Сдаётся мне в это и проблема.

Comment: @SeVlad я ща на этом IP и был. Я временно поставил локальный IP в постоянных ссылках.

Comment: @SeVlad P.S. у меня собственный сервер просто дома стоит, вот и при разработке удобнее через локалку делать

Comment: Ну так я о том что надо сервер нормально настраивать.

Comment: @SeVlad у меня нормальный сервер. Когда был VPS - те же самые проблемы были.

Comment: Ну что сказать.. На правильно настроенных серверах подобной ошибки нет. ВПС ты точно также криво настроил.

Comment: @SeVlad на офф хостинге WordPress тоже самое выдаёт

Comment: Нет никакго "оф. хостинга ВП". Тебя кто-то обманул.

Comment: @SeVlad ошибка с REST API самая распростронёная на WP

Comment: Первая же ссылка из яндекса - возможный вариант решения проблемы: https://ixnfo.com/reshenie-oshibki-s-rest-api-otvet-ne-yavlyaetsya-dopustimym-otvetom-json-wordpress-nginx.html. А так.. отсюда не видно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115592/discussion-between-sevlad-and-kvaksman-play).

Answer (score 1):

Были проблемы с доступом к файлам сайта. Сайт не был владельцем папки и поэтому не имел право редактировать в ней файлы.

Надо было прописать в консоли сервера:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Comment: :) Надо не просто поменять владельца существующих файлов - надо сервер настроить правильно. Иначе ты скоро нарвёшься на разные проблемы.